# .Net Core API with ReactJS Application. Where should Error translates be stored?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Web Api Error Object:

```
public class WebApiError
        {
            public string Error { get; set; }
            public ServiceExceptionCode Code { get; set; }
            public string CodeString { get; set; }
        }
```

What would be better practice, Create extension with for example

```
public class WebApiError
        {
            public string Error { get; set; }
            public ServiceExceptionCode Code { get; set; }
            public string CodeString { get; set; }
            public List<ErrorTranslates> Translates {get;set;}
        }



public class ErrorTranslates
       {
           public Lang Language {get;set;}
           public string ErrorText {get;set;}
           public enum Lang { EN, PL, FR, HU, RUS }
       }
```

Or store error contents showed to user in Frontend. Frontend can check code error, then choose language.

Comment: From your description, it seems that you are creating a multilingual website, if that is the case, the multilingual error messages should be stored in the resource file in the server side, see this articles:[Link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0), [Link2](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/globalization-and-localization-of-model-validation-messages/) and [Link 3](https://www.yogihosting.com/globalization-localization-resource-files-aspnet-core/).